# CollectionView->Animation individual cell with bounce/spring effect

Tags: ios, animation, uicollectionview, collectionview

I am trying to animate individual collection view cell (only the top N cell with the animation for only once when i insert the cell) with bounce effect and wondering is the below the correct function to put the animation? The following code move the cell which is what i wanted but i also would like to have a spring effect at the end.

```
- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes*)initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)itemIndexPath {
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes = [super initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItemAtIndexPath:itemIndexPath];
    attributes.transform =  CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 20.5);
    return attributes;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the POP animation engine, it may provide the animation you are looking for and then some. https://github.com/facebook/pop

Comment: I don't know how to do i attach the spring behavior to the cell. Thanks for the link anyway.

Comment: Have you tried attaching an animation to the cell's layer? I haven't tried it personally, but that's how animation frameworks (like the link above) work.

Comment: Tim, I created a custom flow layout, flow layout attributes and override the applylayoutattributes in the cell and it worked. Thanks for your suggestion.